# Is there an annotation processor to enforce module visibility rules?

Tags: java, annotations, javac

on my project we have about 20 different modules that are packaged as seperate jars each of those jar files have a few packages. Some of the class in those packge are public and thus visible outside the package even though the classes should be treated as private to the module.

Given that Java does not have a built in module system and I don't want to introduce OSGI into my application. I am looking for something along the lines of the @Override annotation that I can stick on types to declare that they are private to a module. Then have some of annotation processor enforce those rules.

Something along the following lines.

```
   @ModuleDefinition
    public class FooModule{} // empty marker class so it can be referenced by other annotations

    @ModulePrivate(FooModule.class)
    public class SomePrivateFooModuleClas{}

    @ModulePublic(FooModule.class)
    public class SomePublicFooModuleClass{}
```

Lets say the following code is located in Another Module

```
   @ModuleDefinition
   public class BarModule{}

    // the annotation processor should generate an error on the import 
    // statement below because the class being imported is module private
    // and the class that the import belong to is not in the same module
    import com.example.SomePrivateFooModuleClass;

    @ModulePrivate(BarModule.class)
    public class SomePrivateBarModuleClas{
        SomePrivateFooModuleClass foo = ... etc    
    }
```

Are there any open source libraries / annotation processor that do something along the lines I have outlined above.

Could such a scheme as outlined above be implemented by an annotation processor or is it beyond the capabilities of what annotation processors are designed to do.

I do not care about runtime isolation of modules, or stopping and reloading modules, or any of the other great features that osgi brings to the table, I just want developers to not use module private classes by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar to what you are looking for. I did not use an annotation processor but used ASM to parse the class files. Check it out at http://www.jabsaw.org

I took a slightly different approach than the one you outline: The modules are also defined as empty marker classes, but the annotation defines which classes belong to the module (by default all classes in the same package). In addition every module defines which modules it imports. Only classes from imported modules may be used.

So my approach is more oriented towards dependency organization.

However, you could reuse the parsing code, either the copy/paste way or with some refactoring.

If I understand you correctly, your modules are currently represented by your jars. Using the parsing code, you could parse all classes in all jars, determining class dependencies and keeping track of the jar the class was parsed from.

Using a `@JarPrivate` without parameters, you could then check if any class uses an `@JarPrivate` class from another jar.

Let me know if you are still interested, I'd be happy to do the required refactoring for you.